# For Selenium automated tests, is there any web application which allows me to select the tests i want to run and start triggering?

Tags: selenium, web-applications, automation, robotframework

I have selenium automated tests. I want to have a UI which allows me to select the tests I want to run. Then start triggering?
Is there any application available like that.
I have tests in Robot Framework Tests using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs, I think you can refer to `robotframework-executor`.
https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-executor/

Comment: Thank you . seems to work for local machine.